# How do I extract the output of Style or Javascript Bundle in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I am working on a single page app that uses a CSS bundle in a .cshtml file as shown below:

@Styles.Render("~/content/css/bundle-css")

However, to improve the loading performance of the site, I would like to embed the entire CSS that was bundled and minified into my .cshtml file. So I would like to convert the code above to look like:

@Html.GetInternalCss("~/content/css/bundle-css");

Where GetInternalCss is an extension method that will take the css virtual path and output an internal css. The code is shown below:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString GetInternalCss(this HtmlHelper html, string styleBundleVirtualPath)
    {
        //TODO:
        var bundledCss = "How do I extract the css from the virtual path?";

        var internalCss = string.Format("<style>{0}</style>", bundledCss);

        return new MvcHtmlString(internalCss);


    }
```

I know the bundled css is in memory somewhere. I just need to know how to get it out. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Could you post as an answer rather than an edit?

Answer (score 0):

I may have answered my own question with the code below:

```
    using System.Collections.Concurrent;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Optimization;

    namespace SomeNameSpace
    {

        public static class HtmlHelpExtensions
        {
            private static readonly IDictionary<string,string> InternalCssCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(); 

            public static MvcHtmlString GetInternalCss(this HtmlHelper html, string styleBundleVirtualPath)
            {
                string internalCss = null;
                if (InternalCssCache.TryGetValue(styleBundleVirtualPath, out internalCss))
                    return new MvcHtmlString(internalCss);

                //download the css
                var relativeUrl = Styles.Url(styleBundleVirtualPath);
                var url = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url + relativeUrl.ToString().Trim('/');
                var webClient = new WebClient();
                var css = webClient.DownloadString(url);

                internalCss = string.Format("<style>{0}</style>", css);
                InternalCssCache[styleBundleVirtualPath] = internalCss;

                return new MvcHtmlString(internalCss);
            }
        }

    }
```